# How to efficiently filter/create mask of numpy.array based on list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I try to create mask of numpy.array based on list of tuples. Here is my solution that produces expected result:

```
import numpy as np

filter_vals = [(1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)] 
data = np.array([
    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]],
    [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]],
])

mask = np.array([], dtype=bool)
for f_val in filter_vals:
    if mask.size == 0:
        mask = (data == f_val).all(-1)
    else:
        mask = mask | (data == f_val).all(-1)
```

Output/mask:

```
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]]
```

Problem is that with bigger `data` array and increasing number of tuples in `filter_vals`, it is getting slower.
It there any better solution? I tried to use `np.isin(data, filter_vals)`, but it does not provide result I need.

Comment: can you give the approximate dimensions of the real use case data? (shape of data and len of filter_vals)

Comment: @mozvay: in real case data is RGB  image e.g. 1440 x 2560. filter_vals contains different colors (e.g. not color range) - depends what should be detected on image. It should be fast at input image could be output from video...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classical approach using broadcasting would be:

```
*A, B = data.shape
(data.reshape((-1,B)) == np.array(filter_vals)[:,None]).all(-1).any(0).reshape(A)
```

This will however be memory expensive. So applicability really depends on your use case.

output:

```
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]])
```